# Loading Dialog from JSON - BotFramework V4

Tags: c#, botframework

I was working on Chatbots based on the Microsoft BotFramework of late 2016 to early 2017 and was wondering if there is a new way of creating dialogs from a static source like a JSON with the new Framework version 4?

In Version 3 there was [this (*Microsoft Docs*)](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-json-schema?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) style. With V4 I can't see such possibilities. In 2017 on some Microsoft conference they talk about some kind of dialogflow builder UI in a deep dive season (sadly all recordings are gone from the ignite library). While I understand this was no super official announcement - are there any tools to use for the business side to build simple dialog flows for the Microsoft BotFramework purely on UI elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've seen, FormFlow was included in the V3 SDK in two forms: with and without the JSON schema. There actually is a way to use [FormFlow in V4](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/tree/master/libraries/Bot.Builder.Community.Dialogs.FormFlow), but only without the JSON schema.

The Bot Framework can do many things, as you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/?view=azure-bot-service-4.0). You might have look to see if there's anything that suits your needs.

More UI-based tools and JSON functionality does sound good to me. You might consider making a [feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/new?template=-net-sdk-feature-request.md). Of course, since the SDK is open source it's always possible to build such features yourself. In any case, you should expect to see more Bot Framework enhancements in the future.